# Python : Pandas Chaining : How to add text to the plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, chaining

How to add text/label to a bar plot, **when using pandas chaining** ? Below is how I'm plotting without the label.

```
(
  df
  .groupby(['col1','col2'], dropna=False)
  [['col1', 'col2']]
  .size()
  .unstack()
  .plot(kind='bar', figsize = (8,8))
 )
```

The unstacked data frame (right before .plot in the above code) has data as below.

```
col2    1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     NaN
col1
 1.0    514    1922    7827   18877    1966
 2.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    2018
 NaN     21      20      59      99    5570
```

The plot is as below:
[image]

I would like to have the numbers displayed on top of the bars. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the output of your chaining (return an Axes instance):

```
ax = (df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], dropna=False)[['col1', 'col2']]
        .size().unstack()
        .plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8, 8)))

for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars)
```

Output:

[image]

**Update**

> I'm using 3.3.2 and cannot upgrade due to system restrictions

```
for rect in ax.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.annotate(r'{:d}'.format(int(height)),
                xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                xytext=(0, 3),
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Corralien. But looks like bar_label came in with matplotlib version 3.4 and above. Unfortunately I'm using 3.3.2 and cannot upgrade due to system restrictions. Is there any other way to get this done ?

Comment: @Geeths https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html maybe this will help with your issue

Comment: Wow !! thank you so much @Corralien. It worked perfect.
Thank you SahilYadav for your inputs.